# Displaying Bootstrap alert while saving to SQLite is successful

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sinatra, haml, datamapper

I want to display to user a flash/alert with proper info about the result of saving to database. I'm building a simple **Sinatra** app with **Twitter bootstrap**. ORM of choice is **DataMapper** and template language is **HAML**.

This is the `POST` method used for registering device in database:

```
post '/register' do
  @device = Device.new( :id       => params[:id],
                        :owner    => params[:owner],
                        :os       => params[:os])

  if @device.save
    puts "Saving device to database - SUCCESS"
    redirect '/'
  else
    puts"Saving device to database - FAILURE"
    redirect '/'
  end
end
```

As you can see, now I'm redirecting to the root path but I want to display in current view alart with this message.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds like [Sinatra::Flash](https://github.com/SFEley/sinatra-flash)

This save your message in a session and show it on your page (your layout file).